# C# 2.0 or 3.5 Design best practices for a dashboard application

Tags: c#

I am designing a dashboard application (An asp.net web app) where I get the latest updated data in a  grid format. The grid should contain all the real time info. The dataaccess is from most of the tables and may have a 1-many relations and aggregates. So for each record,  I loop thru 100's of tables to get the aggregates of all tables. What are the best practices for designing a dashboard application which is database read intensive. I am expecting more than 1000's to be able to access the app at a time. Any Design patterns I should follow? or any best practices etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If your data doesn't need to be absolutely real-time, you could cache your results so queries don't have to be run so often.

Performing lookups across hundreds of tables sounds like it will perform really badly when a lot of traffic starts hitting it. You should cache stuff as much as possible. Even if you only cache the data for 20-30 seconds, it will be better than always retrieving data in real time.

How you go about doing this depends on your architecture. If using ASP.NET, you could look into Microsoft's [ASP.NET Caching Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx) for some better ideas.